# Redirecting URL like /xyz to /index.php?goto=xyz

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Im trying to rewrite a request from an URL like:

`www.domain.com/xyz`

to

`www.domain.com/index.php?goto=xyz`

The plan is to handle requests myself then in index.php. It would be nice if the URL would stay `www.domain.com/xyz`, and it would be also nice to not redirect when there really is a folder called `xyz`.

Ive tried this:

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?goto=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

But this does not keep the URL, doesn't check if there is already the folder xyz and most of all it always goes to index.php?goto=index.php

Andy help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for existence of files and directories in your rule. Keep this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?goto=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great so far! Theres one little problem left. If i request an URL like /test and test is a real folder, it redirects me to index.php?goto=index.php instead of going to that specific folder.

Comment: That won't happen with these rules. Clear your browser cache and retry.

Comment: Soon after I did this, i got a PHP fatal error: allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted. Had this rewrite caused a side effect?

Comment: No rewrite rule is not related to PHP error. Look into your php.ini to allocate more memory or there may be some PHP code issue.